# Adding Application Insights on CardAction of button

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-application-insights

I am new to Microsoft Bot Framework. I am logging custom events on Application
Insights. I am unable to figure out how can i log custom events on button clicks.
Is there a way I could call my TrackCustomEvent function in CardAction of button?

Comment: I have solved the issue.Its not a best solution but I managed to get away with it.
In case someone else looks for similar problem, here's what i did:
-I created a web page and sets the Card Action value to the url of that page. Along with a url i have passed a key which contains the actual url.
On the page load, I call my Track CustomEvent function and then redirects the user to the actual url.

Comment: you should add that as an answer, with details, and then accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add telemetry inside your code (in C#) like the following. 
Notice that I supposed you are created telemetry service in azure, 
and get you `InstrumentationKey`.

```
var ai = new TelemetryClient();
ai.InstrumentationKey = "<your instrumentation key from azure>";
ai.TrackTrace("Hello! " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
ai.TrackTrace("Info " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), SeverityLevel.Information, 
     // Here you can add a structure into the log
     new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "UserId", activity.GetChannelData<object>()}}
);
ai.Flush(); // it sends the logs into the telemetry service
```

Also, you should set some configs and add some references. it can be followed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29441498/3768871).